# No obvious indication how to help edit wikis for those without reputation

Tags: support, bug, tag-wikis

I came across the [unidentifiable](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unidentifiable) tag and noticed it lacks a wiki and the solicitation to help by creating one. The link goes to an About page with nothing there. I understand not having 20k reputation I don't have extra buttons or links, but then why ask us low rep users to help? Is this a bug?

I understand already that they would then be reviewed by others.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to our attention: the [tag:unidentifiable] tag is no more. Tags are supposed to categorize questions to help attract people who know about that category; no-one's an expert in unidentifiability. cf. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: The [tag:bits] tag doesn't have a wiki and is less likely to get nuked (though it might get split into [drill-bits] and [driver-bits] at some point).

Comment: Still, there are other tags without wikis, how is someone without 20k reputation supposed to suggest one for review as is solicited if we don't have a prompt to do so. I looked at tags in Meta DIY and I have it, but not DIY

Comment: So what exactly was the issue that kept me from seeing the edit button? Was this a remanant of a tag that had been deleted, therefore it couldn't be edited? Or shall I delete this non-issue question since it has been fixed?